# progress and download big files from internet problem c#

Tags: c#, winforms, file, download, progress-bar

Hello I have a problem when using this code to download files.
When I download small files like jpg or png it works great,
but when I try to download big files like tar, rar or zip
I have a problem with the progress bar.

This is my code

```
    WebClient client;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = textBox1.Text;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath);
                        client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, Application.StartupPath + "/" + filename);
                });
                thread.Start();
            }
        }
and this in form load

    client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged;
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;
and this is the operator

     private void Client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
            {
                progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
                double reciverd = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
                double total = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
                double precentage = e.ProgressPercentage;
                label1.Text = $"Downloaded{string.Format("{0:0##}", precentage)}%";
                //progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(precentage).ToString());
                progressBar1.Value = (int)precentage;

                

            }));
        }
```

#### Edited

Now the progress bar and download is working, but it goes straight from 0 to 100 when the download is finished and The level of progress is not seen.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212947/discussion-on-question-by-nooby-sharp-progress-and-download-big-files-from-inten).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do progress reporting between discrete code lines.

If you want to have deep reporting (progress per file, rather then progress per batch) you have a few options:

- find a Class that can do this work, and actually has Events for progress reporting. Some never classes do
- Reverse engineer the entire inner loop of the download process (the one that keeps requestion chunks of file to download)
- Do it like the Windows Update team and realize that it is just too much work to bother. And do not bother.

This is one of those things that is way more work then it should be, and way less worth it then it seems.

Comment: _"find a Class that can do this work, and actually has Events for progress reporting. Some never classes do"_ The old one he is using does. The newer HttpClient does not (directly) ... But **we still don't know his actual problem**. I guess, whatever it is, it can be fixed in his approach, I just wouldn't recommend even trying to.

Comment: @NOOBYSHARP Our problem is, you haven't told us what the actual problem with the bigger files _is_. We do not see your screen ;D Please add the problem / exception / whatever you are facing to the question.

Comment: @NOOBYSHARP That error sounds not at all related to Progress reporting. Unless maybe you try to set a "current" or "max" value that is actually negative? How did you get that value negative? Where did you get that value from? Do you use a large enough (signed) Integer to hold the values?

Comment: @Christopher  I'm using google drive link are the problem in gdrive